# AWS: How to deploy docker instance near instantly on ec2 closest to my customer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a basic docker image containing a python script that comes in under 100mb. I'm not sure what distro I'm going to use but preferably one that results in the smallest file size as possible.

The goal is to deploy a docker image on t2.nano ec2 instance but it must meet the following conditions:

- from the time a customer requests access via URL, it should respond as quickly as possible, preferably under a few seconds.
- the latency between the customer and newly deployed docker ec2 instance should be as small as possible, meaning ec2 on the closest availability region.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to deploy an EC2 instance in under a few seconds, especially not t2.nano type instances.  EC2 instances follow the same rules as physical compute resources, thus larger instance types boot faster, and t2.nano is currently the smallest/least powerful/slowest instance size.  That said, even the fastest instances would take a minute or so to be provisioned and fully booted.

It sounds like you should look into using [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/).  It's their proprietary, managed, containerized compute resource service, and designed for the kind of workflow you are describing.  You don't manage the containers themselves, but deploy the code (of which Python is a supported language) and its dependent libraries to the service, and it handles launching it in a container on demand, with overhead in the sub-second range.

Note that it is not designed for hosting "websites" directly, if that's your intention.  Lambda functions are invoked by other AWS services, one of which is [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/), which would be the best route in providing a public interface to your Lambda functions.  This could be used in conjunction with something like [S3 static website hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) to provide the building blocks for a "serverless" web application.

As for your second question, Route 53 does support [latency based routing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-latency), but I don't believe it supports API Gateway endpoints as targets yet.  So if global latency is a big concern, your best bet may be to deploy a few full-time EC2 instances around the world and use latency based routing.  If it's mainly static assets you're worried about, [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront) can cache these at edge locations, as an alternative.